# Speeding Up the VBA Code

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I am having troubled times with my code which is basically matching the reference numbers from two workbooks and writing the related information to a new worksheet. First of all, let me give some details about the sizes. One of the workbooks has 1987 rows and 66 columns and the other one has 15645 rows and 13 columns. The new worksheet after the code has 5643 rows and 41 columns. On average code runs for 2 minutes and 10 seconds which is too long in my case. I've tried several things to speed up my code, however, it didn't work out. Thanks a lot for any kind of help!

```
   Sub take_swap_values()

   With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .DisplayStatusBar = False
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                .EnableEvents = False
   End With


    Dim h, f As Long
    Dim r As Integer

    h = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Workbooks("swap.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet3").Range("$B$2:$B$1987"))
    f = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$A$5645"))

    Workbooks("swap.xlsx").Activate
    Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Activate
    Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

    For i = 1 To h
        For j = 1 To f
            If Workbooks("swap.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value = Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                For k = 1 To 40
                    Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k).Value = Workbooks("swap.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, k)
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .DisplayStatusBar = True
       .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       .EnableEvents = True
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Technically, if you're looking for advice on improving working code rather than fixing a bug, you should post the code to [codereview.se] rather than here; however you have three nested loops iterating over large ranges; it's unlikely that approach is going to be rapid

Comment: You could probably post what you've done to try to speed up this code and it would greatly improve the quality of this question.

Comment: Looks like you could rewrite this with a SQL statement. That should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Ryan Writing with SQL did really become faster, thanks for the advice

Comment: Nested loops in which every item in one range is compared with every item in another range can usually be eliminated by loading the values in one of the two ranges into a dictionary and then looping over the other range, checking the values in that range against the dictionary.

Comment: @JohnColeman I wasn't aware that dictionaries exist in vba. I will try to do it in your way and report the outcome. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with arrays to speed up code where you need to iterate through lots of data.
Try the code below...I've commented it to help explain the different parts.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
    Option Explicit 'always use this ... it will help eliminate simple errors in coding and variables

   Sub take_swap_values()
   'declare your variables
   Dim swpWB As Workbook
   Dim swpWS As Worksheet
   Dim swpRng As Range
   Dim swpArr 'array variable

   Dim swp_fwdWB As Workbook
   Dim swp_fwdWS1 As Worksheet
   Dim swp_fwdWS2 As Worksheet
   Dim swp_fwdRng As Range
   Dim swp_fwdArr 'array variable

   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .DisplayStatusBar = False
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                .EnableEvents = False 'probably don't need this unless there are worksheet change macros running
   End With

   'instantiate your variables
   Set swpWB = Application.Workbooks("swap.xlsx")
   Set swpWS = swpWB.Sheets("Sheet3")
   Set swpRng = swpWS.Range("$B$2:$B$1987")

   Set swp_fwdWB = Application.Workbooks("swp_fwd.xlsm")
   Set swp_fwdWS1 = swp_fwdWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set swp_fwdRng = swp_fwdWS1.Range("$A$2:$A$5645")

   Set swp_fwdWS2 = swp_fwdWB.Sheets("Sheet2")

    swp_fwdWS2.Cells(1, 1).Value = swp_fwdWS1.Cells(1, 1).Value

    'fill arrays with values from the ranges
    swpArr = swpRng.Value
    swp_fwdArr = swp_fwdRng.Value

    'loop through each array ... these are one dimensional arrays meaning they have only a multiplicity of rows and not rows and columns
    For i = LBound(swpArr) To UBound(swpArr) 'Lbound stands for Lower Bound and Ubound stands for Upper Bound
        For j = LBound(swp_fwdArr) To UBound(swp_fwdArr)
            If swpArr(i, 1) = swp_fwdArr(j, 1) Then
                'set value of entire range from column 1 to column 40 on that row to the same range of columns for swpWS
                With swp_fwdWS2
                    .Range(.Cells(j + 1, 1), .Cells(j + 1, 40)).Value = swpWS.Range(swpWS.Cells(i + 1, 1), swpWS.Cells(i + 1, 40)).Value  'a 1 gets added because the array does not include the header column
                End With
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .DisplayStatusBar = True
       .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       .EnableEvents = True
   End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: I tested on dummy data and the code took 5 seconds to loop through the range...granted it only found a match twice, but 5 seconds to loop through that much data is blazing!

Comment: Agree with mongoose. Putting data into memory helps a lot!